# Batman Arkham City Augmented Reality (PC)

Tags: batman-arkham-city

So I was trying to do the Augmented Reality side quests. I did the first ones just fine and got the upgraded grapple. Now I'm on the Advanced missions. I looked online and saw on here and other forums and in videos. Hold Space, press and hold <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd> while still holding <kbd>Space</kbd>, then release <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd>.

However,  every time I release <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd> Batman instantly shoots way up instead of just gliding forward. I've been flying around the city to practice and so far nothing I have done is making a difference.

Could anyone help me understand please?

Comment: Aim downwards after dive bombing to counteract the altitude boost. Dive bombing gives an altitude and speed boost, but if you don't want the altitude, you can point Batman in a lower direction. This is pretty useful when you just want to maintain a level trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the mouse, you have to rapidly move it downwards after releasing Ctrl - the default movement boost will be upwards, but you can aim and move horizontally; you just have to do it quickly enough to level before you rise too high, and precisely enough to avoid landing.